# how to use ng-checked and ng-disabled with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-scope

i was facing problems with ng-repeat while using ng-checked and ng-disable with it

```
<div ng-repeat="module in modulelist>
<input id="switch{{$index}}" ng-init="setState($index);" type="checkbox" ng-checked="switch.checked" ng-disabled="switch.disable" ng-click="toggle($index,light.name)" />
```

i am using ng-init to load the state of the checkbox  `module.status`from the modulelist ,status can be ON ,OFF or unknown ,for unknown i want to disable the cb ,for ON/OFF i want to check/uncheck the cb. i tried using

```
$scope.switch={checked:true};
```

but it is applying the property to all the checkbox
i know that 'switch.checked'/'switch.disable' should be unique for each CB to make a unique change,but i am not able to do so.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like what you need. Each module is the model for the input, so you can use logic for those attributes.

```
<div ng-repeat="module in modulelist>
<input id="switch{{$index}}" 
    ng-init="setState($index);" type="checkbox"
    ng-checked="module.status==='ON'"
    ng-disabled="module.status==='unknown'"
    ng-click="toggle($index,light.name)" />
```

Using the below code is using the same scope variable for all the checkboxes, which is why changing one will change them all.

```
$scope.switch={checked:true};
```

### Edit

In response to the OP's comment, something like this:

`ng-checked="handleCheckStatus(module.status)"`

and then on `$scope`:

```
$scope.handleCheckStatus = function(status) {
   switch (status) {
       case 'ON':
           return true;
       break;
       case 'OFF':
           return false;
       break;
       // and so on
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply ..that worked ..I had a small doubt ..say if 'unknown' is anything else then 'on' or 'off' then what to do ??

Comment: @KaranSinghKochar if it's ON, the checkbox will be checked. If it's anything else, it won't be. If the status is unknown, it will be disabled, anything else, it won't be. If you want to add in more commands, I would have it call a function on scope to go through a switch of those commands.